# How to add click event handler to individual img elements?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, mouseclick-event

I'm working on an assignment that is asking me to:

"Add a click event handler to each thumbnail image. When the smaller image is clicked, your code will show the larger version of the image in the  element within the  element. This same even handler will also set the  text of  to the clicked thumbnail image's title attribute. Your event handler must use even delegation."

Here is the provided code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head >
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Chapter 9 - Share Your Travels</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chapter09-project02.js">           </script>   
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <h2>Share Your Travels</h2>
    <nav><img src="images/menu.png"></nav>
</header>
<main>
    <figure id="featured">
    <img src="images/medium/5855774224.jpg" title="Battle" />
    <figcaption>Battle</figcaption>
</figure>
<div id="thumbnails">
    <img src="images/small/5855774224.jpg" title="Battle" />
    <img src="images/small/5856697109.jpg" title="Luneburg" />
    <img src="images/small/6119130918.jpg" title="Bermuda" />
    <img src="images/small/8711645510.jpg" title="Athens" />
    <img src="images/small/9504449928.jpg" title="Florence" />
</div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck. How do I add one single event handler that shows different larger images for each individual thumbnail?

Comment: What's inside your included JS file?  Do you already have a function to show a larger version of the image?  If so, you can call it inside an onclick attribute on the image.  You would do `<img src="..." onclick="functionCall();" />`

Comment: there is no JS file... they only included a css file

Comment: `Here is the provided code` You don't seem to have any code there... post your Javascript if you want help debugging

Comment: It appears to be including something ...  
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chapter09-project02.js">           </script>`  Is that what you're supposed to be creating then?  If so, what have you done so far?

Comment: Yes, that is where we're supposed to be adding our own code. I haven't gotten anywhere so far. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use event delegation for a function that will be unique to each thumbnail element (as in, when clicked on, each thumbnail will reference a different image file) rather than use inline events for each one.